# Add StreamBlock child items programmatically in Wagtail

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I have the following StructBlock and StreamBlock below:

```
class AccordionItemBlock(StructBlock):
    title = CharBlock()
    text = RichTextBlock()

class AccordionRepeaterBlock(StreamBlock):
    accordion_item = AccordionItemBlock()
```

I need to programmatically add it and multiple "item" CharBlocks to this page:

```
class BasicPage(Page):
    body = StreamField([
        ('accordion_repeater_block', AccordionRepeaterBlock()),
    ], null=True)
```

This is how I am approaching it

```
page.body = [
    (
        'accordion_repeater_block',
        {
            'accordion_item',
            {
                'title': 'Title goes here',
                'text': RichText('Testing!'),
            }
        }
    )
]
provider.save()
```

I get errors no matter what I put in the second tuple value after **'accordion_repeater_block'**. Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found the solution! You have to make the child blocks an instance of StreamValue.StreamChild:

```
from wagtail.wagtailcore.blocks.stream_block import StreamValue

page.body = [
    ('accordion_repeater_block',
        [
            StreamValue.StreamChild(
                id=None,
                block=AccordionItemBlock(),
                value={
                        'title': 'Title goes here',
                        'text': RichText('Testing!'),
                }
            ),
        ]
    )
]
page.save()
```

Comment: It will give str does not have attribute get_prep_value() @Preston Horn

Comment: In Wagtail 2.12.3 this has moved: use `from wagtail.core.blocks.stream_block import StreamValue` instead.

Answer (score 3):

For Wagtail 4.1, the accepted answer didn't work for me. This is what did:

```
accordion_item_data = {
  'title': 'Title goes here',
  'text': RichText('Testing!'),
}

page.body = StreamValue(
  stream_block=page.body.stream_block,
  stream_data=[
    {
      "type": "accordion_repeater_block",
      "value": [{"type": "accordion_item", "value": accordion_item_data }]}
  ],
   is_lazy=True,
)
page.save()
```

I had to look at the Wagtail source code and do a lot of trial-and-error as there is no hints on the documentation ヽ(*。>Д<)o゜